# Trying to increment local variable from a separate method but not working. Confusion about Activation Stack/Record

Tags: java, memory, methods, heap-memory, activation-record

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Demo instance = new Demo();
        instance.init();
    }
    public void init() {
        int size = 0;
        inc(size);
        System.out.println(size);
    }
    public int inc(int size){
        size++;
        return size;
    }
}
```

When I call the code above, the number zero is returned.

Even declaring `size` as a class attribute instead of a local variable does not solve the problem. I understand that when a method is complete, the corresponding record (containing local variable and such) is popped off of the activation stack. But, if the `size` variable is declared in the `init()` method, and then incremented and **returned** in a separate method (`inc()`), shouldn't size be equal to 1?

Comment: You're never setting size equal to the return value of the method inc, what if you switch this line: `inc(size);` to this `size = inc(size);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When incrementing you do not assign the value to anything, it increments it, but it does not store it anywhere so the value remains 0, try doing like this.

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Demo instance = new Demo();
        instance.init();
    }
    public void init() 
    {
        int size = 0;
        size = inc(size);
        System.out.println(size);
    }
    public int inc(int size)
    {
        size++;
        return size;
    }
}
```

or like this

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Demo instance = new Demo();
        instance.init();
    }
    public void init() 
    {
        int size = 0;
        System.out.println(inc(size));
    }
    public int inc(int size)
    {
        size++;
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the incrementation basically returns to nothing when popping from the stack in my solution? In your solution it returns to the variable size and gives control back to the init() method?

Comment: yeah, you're right, in your case, the return method returns the "incremented" value nowhere, in my case, it overwrites the current value of size, with the incremented one, returned from inc()

Answer (score 2):

```
size = inc(size);
```

will solve your problem, since you are not using a public scoped variable.

If you want to make this a bit elegant (at least I think this will be a bit more handy), then you need to declare a variable as a class variable.
I will illustrate this to you:

```
public class Demo {    
  int size; //global range variable

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Demo instance = new Demo();
    instance.init();
  }

  public void init() {
    this.size = 0;
    inc();
    System.out.println(this.size);
 }

 public void inc(){
   this.size++; //will increment your variable evertime you call it
 }
}
```